# Is there a way to convert this formula so it is case sensitive and works with numbers too

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

I use the following formula to sum the values corresponding to the characters.

`{=SUM(VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1))),values,2,0))}` . It worked but can't get it to work case-sensitive and with numbers.

If  `a=1.325   b=1.5   A=1.5   2=1.5`    ->

`ab = a+b = 1.325+1.5 = 2.825`

`ab = 2.825` (works)
`Ab = 3` (doesn't work)
`ab2 = 4.325` (doesn't work)
`Ab2 = 4.5` (doesn't work)

Maybe using TRUE index match function, couldn't figure it out.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you tried 'EXACT'?  e.g.  {=EXACT(SUM(VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1))),values,2,0)))}

Comment: Did that work for you?, it didn't work on my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the formula you post, I assume you're using an old  version of Excel, so you should use something like:

`=SUM(INDEX(values,,2)*MMULT(N(EXACT(INDEX(values,,1),MID(A2,TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))^0))`

which will most likely require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for your version of Excel.

Comment: Thank you!!. I am actually using 365, just old school I guess. What would be the modern/365 way to do this?

Comment: what would be the modern/365 way to do this?

Comment: For O365: `=SUM(INDEX(values,,2)*MMULT(N(EXACT(INDEX(values,,1),MID(A2,SEQUENCE(,LEN(A2)),1))),SEQUENCE(LEN(A2),,,0)))`

Answer (score 2):

`VLOOKUP()` is not equipped to do case-sensitive matching. Very few functions actually are. One is `FIND()`. You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)),D$1:D$4),0)*E$1:E$4)
```

Or, in terms of your named range:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)),INDEX(values,,1)),0)*INDEX(values,,2))
```

Just like @JosWoolley I assumed an Excel version prior to ms365. Therefor confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.